PowerBI DAX Calculate the total hours and minutes Per ID
I have a data that has employeee id, employe name, duration. I am trying to calculate the total number of hours and minutes for each employee based on their IDs for example



EmpID
Emp Name
Duration (Minutes)




001
Marc Jacobs
30


001
Marc Jacobs
40


001
Marc Jacobs
80


002
Bruce Wayne
30


002
Bruce Wayne
25


003
Brad Pitt
40


003
Brad Pitt
40


003
Brad Pitt
80



I am trying to achieve this



EmpID
Emp Name
Duration (Minutes)
Total Hours




001
Marc Jacobs
30
2 hours 30 mins


001
Marc Jacobs
40
2 hours 30 mins


001
Marc Jacobs
80
2 hours 30 mins


002
Bruce Wayne
30
55 mins


002
Bruce Wayne
25
55 mins


003
Brad Pitt
40
2 hours 40 mins


003
Brad Pitt
40
2 hours 40 mins


003
Brad Pitt
80
2 hours 40 mins




Please edit your question to show what you have tried. Also please explain the use of the powerquery tag if you are looking for a DAX solution.

you can try to create a column
Column=
VAR total =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Duration (Minutes)] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[EmpID] )
    )
VAR h =
    INT ( total / 60 )
VAR m =
    MOD ( total, 60 )
RETURN
    IF ( h <> 0, h & " hours " & m & " mins", m & " mins" )



Thank you for your response, this seems to be appropriate but the only issue that I am having here is the error message "The function SUM cannot work with values of type String." Is there any that I can adjust that?

What's the type of Duration (Minutes) column? Please make sure its type is whole number, not text

Thank you very much for your help. This has achieved what I have been looking for. I am so glad, this is perfect. Thanks again

you are welcome. pls don't forget to accept this as the answer. thx
